# Datepicker from @Mui does not want to cooperate with react-hooks-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, react-hook-form

In this code I show you code which works (uncomment) and doesn't work(comment)

```
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name="DOB"
            render={({ field }) => (
              <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                <DatePicker
                  // defaultValue={dayjs(defaultvalues.DOB)}
                  value={dobvalue}
                  onChange={(value) => {
                    // field.onChange(value);
                    setDobvalue(value);
                  }}
                  id="DOB"
                  format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                  label={t("Date of Bearth")}
                  // {...register("DOB", {})}
                />
              </LocalizationProvider>
            )}
          />
```

Problem is that I use react-hooks-form and I want to use that in this example too. But all the time if I try use react-hook-form in this from control I have an error when I try to change the date

> caught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Do you know where is the problem? Of course DOB is'nt sending correctly do backend.

@edit

Changed code

```
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name="DOB"
            defaultValue={dayjs(defaultvalues.DOB) || ""}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                <DatePicker
                  value={field.value}
                  onChange={(value) => {
                    field.onChange(value);
                  }}
                  id="DOB"
                  format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                  label={t("Date of Bearth")}
                  {...register("DOB", {})}
                />
              </LocalizationProvider>
            )}
          />
```

Answer (score 0):

first, you should use `field.value` inside your datePicker, then put `defaultValue` in `Controller`. also when you use `Controller` you shouldn't use `register` function, so:

```
<Controller
            control={control}
            name="DOB"
            defaultValue={dayjs(defaultvalues.DOB) || ''}
            render={({ field }) => (
              <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDayjs}>
                <DatePicker
                  value={field.value}
                  onChange={(value) => {
                    field.onChange(value);
                    setDobvalue(value);
                  }}
                  id="DOB"
                  format="YYYY-MM-DD"
                  label={t("Date of Bearth")}
                />
              </LocalizationProvider>
            )}
          />
```

Comment: I changed the code (I want to use register so it looks like in the updated post), but the problem still occurs. I also tried using your code and it works. Well almost, because if I give, for example, the date to 2005-11-11, the date of the previous day is sent, which in this case is 2005-11-10.

Comment: the 1-day difference could be because of your server's time zone or locale. try to tweak them a little bit. maybe it solved your issue.